# Link a Vaadin app with a database using Derby and Spring JDBC

Tags: spring, jdbc, vaadin

I'm currently working on a web application that must be linked to a database with the following requirements :

-Vaadin for the app

-Derby to create the database

-Spring jdbc to connect to it and for the sql requests

I was able to select and update the elements in the database and then store it in a List for example but I want to bind them so when I change an element, it changes the database as well. 
I read about SQLContainer but then I'll have to use a connection pool which I can't have with Spring.

Here's how I connect to the database right now:

```
dao= new DerbyDao();
DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:derby:D:\\Database;");
dataSource.setUsername("user");
dataSource.setPassword("pass");
dao.setDataSource(dataSource);
dao.createTable();
```

My DerbyDao class is where I put my requests. For exemple

```
public void createTable(){
  JdbcTemplate insert = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        String sql="CREATE TABLE app.personsregistred( " +
                "ID int generated by default as identity (start with 1) not null, " +
                "name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, " +
                "connexionDate date, " +
                "login VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, " +
                "password VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL," +
                "PRIMARY KEY (ID))";

             insert.update(sql);    
    }
```

So from here, I don't know how to use the SQLContainer. 
Please if you have any solution, I'll be very glad to hear it. Thank you